# kernels of states on C* algebras

Tags: oa.operator-algebras

Given a unital $C^*$ algebra $A$ and a subspace $W\subset A$ which does not contain 1, (a) what conditions on $W$ are needed to show that there is at least one normalised state whose kernel contains $W$, and (b) what conditions on $W$ are needed so say that there is exactly one such state?

I am sure that this is a known problem, and would be very happy if some people could point me in the right direction. This problem arose in considering integrals on noncommutative spaces and the corresponding divergences of noncommutative vector fields.

Comment: A linear function $f$ is a state iff $\|f\|=1=f(1)$. So, (a) iff $d(W,1)=1$, in turn, iff $W$ does not contain an element $x$ such that $x+x^*$ is positive invertible.

Comment: That is really useful! I could make it an answer if you formatted it that way...